# directory specific org-download-link-format not working

Tags: org-mode, inline-image

I want a separate saving of my personal static images in a sub-directory:
`~/org/static/personal` instead of `~/org/static`. Hence I'm trying to add a `.dir-locals.el` file in my personal subdirectory `~/org/personal/`

*This is my main org-download config:*

```
(setq org-download-image-dir "~/org/static/"
        org-download-heading-lvl nil
        org-download-image-attr-list
        '("#+ATTR_ORG: :width 1000")
        )

(after! org-download
  (setq org-download-method 'directory
        org-download-timestamp ""
        org-download-link-format "[[file:~/org/static/%s]]\n"
))
```

*Here is my attempted `.dir-locals.el`:*

```
((nil . ((org-download-image-dir . "~/org/static/personal/")))
(nil . ((eval (after! org-download (org-download-link-format "[[file:~/org/static/personal/%s]]\n"))))))
```

Emacs is correctly reading the first line and saving the images in `~/org/static/personal`, but it's not recognizing the new `org-download-link-format` value. Hence the inline link of the image is coming incorrect - `[[file:~/org/static/abc.png]]` in stead of `[[file:~/org/static/personal/abc.png]]`.